# Nothing displaying in console when using console.log with if statements in for loops

Tags: javascript

I have two objects:

```
var obj = { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" };
var search = { last: "Montague" };
```

My goal is to find if the second object (`search`) is present in the first one, and `console.log` it if it is.

First, I get the keys of both objects:

```
var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
var searchKeys = Object.keys(search);
```

Then I am trying to iterate trough both keys and compare them, and if they match, `console.log` the value from the first obj (`obj`).

```
//for every key in object
for(var x = 0; x < objKeys.lenght; x++) {
  //for every key in search
  for(var y = 0; y < searchKeys.length; y++) {
    //see if a key matches
    if(searchKeys[y] == objKeys[x]) {
        //see if the value matches
        if(obj[objKeys[x]] == search[searchKeys[y]]) {
        console.log(obj[objKeys[x]]);
      }  
      else {
        console.log("value not found");
      }
    }
    else {
        console.log("key not found");
    }
  } 
}
```

Now when I run this code, nothing displays in the console. No errors or messages. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

I've create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdbw58r8/2/) of this code, if you want to tinker.

Comment: You have a typo: `lenght`

Comment: its the typo - just tested in fiddle

Comment: thanks, got it working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled `length` in the first loop.

Also consider using `for-in` loop like:

```
for (property in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       //...
   }
}
```